# Strange numbers when assigning values to a netCDF4 Variable

Tags: python, netcdf

On a system with Python 3.3.2, Numpy 1.7.1 and Pyhton-netcdf4 1.0.4, I am experimenting this:

```
> from netCDF4 import Dataset
> f = Dataset('testfile.nc4', 'a')
> seqs = f.groups('calibration_params').variables['calibration_sequence']
> print(seqs[:])
[(1, 1, 1000, 500) (2, 1, 1000, 500) (3, 3, 1000, 500) (4, 1, 1000, 500) 
 (5, 2, 1000, 500) (6, 1, 10000, 0) (7, 1, 1000, 500) (8, 1, 1000, 500) 
 (9, 0, 1000, 500)]
> tmp = seqs[:]
> tmp[0][3] = 0
> print(tmp)
[(1, 1, 1000, 0) (2, 1, 1000, 500) (3, 3, 1000, 500) (4, 1, 1000, 500) 
 (5, 2, 1000, 500) (6, 1, 10000, 0) (7, 1, 1000, 500) (8, 1, 1000, 500) 
 (9, 0, 1000, 500)]
> seqs[:] = tmp
> print(seqs[:])
[(1, 2, 3, 4) (5, 6, 7, 8) (9, 1283, 1, 40960) (0, 0, 0, 49536) 
 (0, 0, 44312, 0) (0, 35008, 0, 0) (49440, 1, 40960, 0)
 (0, 43312, 29442, 0) (34960, 8660, 0, 34912)]
> print(tmp)
    [(1, 1, 1000, 0) (2, 1, 1000, 500) (3, 3, 1000, 500) (4, 1, 1000, 500) 
     (5, 2, 1000, 500) (6, 1, 10000, 0) (7, 1, 1000, 500) (8, 1, 1000, 500) 
     (9, 0, 1000, 500)]
```

As you can see, it is not completely random, but I cannot figure out the source of the problem. I checked the formats, but everything (both seqs and tmp array) is '< u2'. Any clue about what is going wrong?

Comment: Could you make your test file available so people can test it?

Comment: It is not possible for some confidential information contained in other parts of the file. I could try to strip anything but this table, so that it could be distributed. On the other hand, I could accomplish my goal (setting a value to 0) using h5py.

Comment: Just wondering if you could set up a test case file. I haven't experienced this error myself, was just curious.